# Can I exclude imported .scss files when compiling

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, postcss

I want to make an addon to the Bootstrap framework and want to use some variables, mixins, functions, etc with my own code/classes. But when I compile the project I don't want to compile the whole Bootstrap project along with my own code.

Example: I want to make a new button type and need the theme colors.

**app.scss**

```
/* The Bootstrap library */
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

/* My own components */
@import "my-button.scss";
```

I then use PostCSS to compile app.scss. Can I use the theme maps and contrast calculations from the Bootstrap files but not compile the whole Bootstrap project into my `app.css` file?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can import parts of the files to access variables, maps and functions. The whole thing is described in the Bootstrap documentation.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/customize/sass/

Here is an example:

```
// Custom.scss
// Option B: Include parts of Bootstrap

// 1. Include functions first (so you can manipulate colors, SVGs, calc, etc)
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";

// 2. Include any default variable overrides here

// 3. Include remainder of required Bootstrap stylesheets
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";

// 4. Include any default map overrides here

// 5. Include remainder of required parts
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/maps";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";

/* My own components */
@import "my-button.scss";
```